# Python key gen that can be used 1 time and check its valid

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey im learning python and i would like to make a script that requires a licence key, but i want to make it require a personal key, for example they would have to purchase the programme/key to then proceed to the next stage. but i want it so that the key is generated and can only be used once.

```
activeKey = "Test"

enterActiveKey = input("Please enter the activation key down below:\\n")
if activeKey == enterActiveKey:
print("Activation key is successful.")
while activeKey != enterActiveKey:
print("Activation key is incorrect. Please re-run the program")
break
```

I made this script that i can specifically chose a activation key but i want it so that the key is generated and only possible to be used 1 time so i dont need to specify the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done,because unique id generation is not possible, even UUID have collision risk,
So the best way is maintaining a Database,
As you say user have to purchase the key, this means you have a website so you can try
mysql,
mongodb atlas(free for some extend ) even sqlite,
any kind of database is ok,
See
[tutorial for database connectivity](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-database-tutorial/amp/)

**Here is the very basic flow:**

*

1. You generate any uuid key then store that in database
2. When user purchase a key, update the database that this key is sold
3. Now when user enter that key in your program check Database that if
   this key is present and sold

- 

you can now add your logic to make it better.

Comment: Thank you i will look into this much apricated.